# Data appears in the simulator but not in the device

Tags: iphone

I have developed a simple To-Do application with a simple database.problem is that my database only shows data in the simulator.when I load it to the phone,it doesn't show up the data.the console shows an error message saying "My table doesn't exists".hope someone can help me coz it's critical....

Thanks.

Comment: the problem is most likely that you are only moving the application to the phone, and not both the application and the database

Comment: how can I do tht?.I have added the database to my resources folder and also i have added the libsqlite3.0.dylib framework as well.btw I'm installing the application by plugging my phone to the machine and running from X-code.please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your app from the device. Then make a clean build, and reinstall it.
when you make modifications in the data architecture, you need to re-install the app.